# Unable to chat. Kinda Suspension?

Tags: bug, chat, account-suspension

I am temporarily suspended at Chem.SE, Now even though I have 99%(kinda) positive record on Math.SE, I am unable to chat in Math groups too!

Comment: You might find more on meta.SE. For example, the problem explained in this feature request might be related to your problem: [Don't extend suspensions from the parent site to chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145235/dont-extend-suspensions-from-the-parent-site-to-chat).

Comment: Your chat history seems to be reasonable so I've gone ahead and changed your chat parent site to math.SE.